# Adding and removing elements from doctrine mongodb ODM results - PHP

Tags: php, symfony-2.1, doctrine-odm

How do you remove and add elements to results returned by doctrine's odm. For example,

I have the query

`$fruits =  $dm->createQueryBuilder('Fruits')
              ->field('id')->in($fruit_list)
              ->getQuery()->execute();`

$fruits returned is an arrayand then I need to iterate through this 
array and filter some fruits after some analysis. The shortlisting is 
not possible through the query builder and I need to return the filtered
results.

I wanted to ask how to remove elements from this object returned by odm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are iterating over `$fruits` and making your shortlisting decision, create an [ArrayCollection](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) and add all the objects that make the cut and return that rather than the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand you, I'll assume you're trying to eliminate some fields from the entities that were returned by the ODM.

I'd turn off the hydration and work with a simple array.

Example:

```
$fruits = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Fruits')
             ->field('id')
             ->in($fruit_list)
             ->hydrate(false) /* Turn off hydration */
             ->getQuery()->execute();
```

Now all you have to do is to use unset and remove the wanted elements from the array.

Comment: Thanks but I have to deal with 2 cases - one with hydration and one without it. I have already taken care of the non hydrated case like you said.
But it would be great if I can do it for the hydrated objects also. So, are there any operations like unset, remove for the hydrated objects.

Comment: You can't remove fields from php objects ant it has nothing to do with doctrine... What do you do with those objects ? You can set field value to null if it helps